# Whtmltopdf fail to create PDF

Tags: c#, iis, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to convert a dynamic HTML page to a PDF file using `wkhtmltopdf` with `Codaxy C# Wrapper`.
It works fine on the local machine, but when I try to publish it / upload it to the `IIS server`,

It gives me: `Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError`.

Please help me :D

Comment: Post some code so we can help you

Comment: Hi I have already resolved the issue by changing the code wrapper. I used https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin instead of codaxy. ^_^ Thank you for your comment :D

Comment: Please post it as answer so that your question doesn't remain unanswered. Guidelines suggest to do Q&A so A must be there too :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution used by the user who created this question.

> Hi I have already resolved the issue by changing the code wrapper.
>   I used http://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin instead of codaxy.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have already resolved the issue by changing the code wrapper. I used https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin instead of codaxy. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Could the error be that the url you gave wasn't accessible by your server ?

For other people, we can write a little method in PdfConvert.cs in Codaxy.WkHtmlToPdf to give html generated, for exemple, in our controller :

```
public static void ConvertHtmlToPdf(string htmlHeader, string htmlContent, string htmlFooter, PdfOutput output)
{
    String inputHeaderFilePath;
    String inputContentFilePath;
    String inputFooterFilePath;

    inputHeaderFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.TempFolderPath, String.Format("{0}.html", Guid.NewGuid()));
    inputContentFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.TempFolderPath, String.Format("{0}.html", Guid.NewGuid()));
    inputFooterFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.TempFolderPath, String.Format("{0}.html", Guid.NewGuid()));

    // Feed Temp files
    File.WriteAllText(inputHeaderFilePath, htmlHeader);
    File.WriteAllText(inputContentFilePath, htmlContent);
    File.WriteAllText(inputFooterFilePath, htmlFooter);

    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument() { HeaderUrl = inputHeaderFilePath, Url = inputContentFilePath, FooterUrl = inputFooterFilePath };
    ConvertHtmlToPdf(document, output);

    //Remove Temp files
    File.Delete(inputHeaderFilePath);
    File.Delete(inputContentFilePath);
    File.Delete(inputFooterFilePath);
}
```

What do you think about it ?